# WARNING: Skipping entry because it is not an absolute URI. GlassFish in NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans, glassfish

I successfully installed GlassFish. However, when I start a server, I get this two warning messages:

**WARNING: Skipping entry  because it is not an absolute URI.**

What is that about ?

```
Launching GlassFish on Felix platform
Aug 09, 2014 10:38:38 PM com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner createBundleProvisioner
INFO: Create bundle provisioner class = class com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner.
Aug 09, 2014 10:38:38 PM com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner$DefaultCustomizer getLocations
WARNING: Skipping entry  because it is not an absolute URI.
Aug 09, 2014 10:38:38 PM com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner$DefaultCustomizer getLocations
WARNING: Skipping entry  because it is not an absolute URI.
Registered com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.EmbeddedOSGiGlassFishRuntime@162cf6a in service registry.
Registry Info:: Total repositories: 1, Total modules = 293
...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You can safely ignore this warning.**

It comes from `com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner`. This part of GlassFish installs/registers the GlassFish modules from the `modules` folder. It loops through a list of URIs, i.e. the file paths of the modules.

If an URI is not absolute, i.e. it is relative or it has no scheme component, then this class logs this warning. In this case the URIs are not absolute because GlassFish probably uses the paths relative from the GlassFish root.

Comment: I'm new to JavaEE and Glassfish. I hope it won't make any problems later. Thank you on the reply!

Answer (score 6):

unwichtich is right that the warning can be ignored but you can also get rid of it.

To get rid of the warning edit the file `<glassfish_home>/glassfish/config/osgi.properties` and change the **core.bundles** property from:

```
core.bundles=\
    ${com.sun.aas.installRootURI}modules/endorsed/ \
    ${obr.bundles} \
    ${hk2.bundles} \
    ${com.sun.aas.installRootURI}modules/glassfish.jar
```

to:

```
core.bundles=\
    ${com.sun.aas.installRootURI}modules/endorsed/ \
    ${hk2.bundles} \
    ${com.sun.aas.installRootURI}modules/glassfish.jar
```

The warning is happening because BundleProvisioner reads a property in osgi.properties named **glassfish.osgi.auto.start** and it in turn references other properties like **core.bundles**.

The property that was removed above, **obr.bundles**, is currently commented out. The comment is expanded to a space which BundleProvisioner reads and issues a warning about.