# "The module has not been deployed. See the server log for details"

Tags: java, netbeans

I have created Enterprise application in netbeans but whenever i run am receiving this error i uninstalled and then install the application so many times even i pointed glassfish server but i have failed. please help an new to java and netbeans. below i attached my server log and the error.

In-place deployment at \Mac\Home\Downloads\EPDAssignment\EPDAssignment-war\build\web
GlassFish Server 4.1, deploy, null, false
\\Mac\Home\Downloads\EPDAssignment\EPDAssignment-war\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1051: The module has not been deployed.
See the server log for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)

[Server Log screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/clX6Z.png)

```
Info:   Server shutdown initiated
Info:   Unregistered com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.EmbeddedOSGiGlassFishImpl@6014a9ba from service registry.
Info:   FileMonitoring shutdown
Info:   JMXStartupService: Stopped JMXConnectorServer: null
Info:   JMXStartupService and JMXConnectors have been shut down.
Info:   JdbcRuntimeExtension,  getAllSystemRAResourcesAndPools = [GlassFishConfigBean.org.glassfish.jdbc.config.JdbcResource, GlassFishConfigBean.org.glassfish.jdbc.config.JdbcResource, GlassFishConfigBean.org.glassfish.jdbc.config.JdbcResource, GlassFishConfigBean.org.glassfish.jdbc.config.JdbcConnectionPool, GlassFishConfigBean.org.glassfish.jdbc.config.JdbcConnectionPool, GlassFishConfigBean.org.glassfish.jdbc.config.JdbcConnectionPool]
Completed shutdown of Log manager service
Info:   Shutdown procedure finished
Completed shutdown of GlassFish runtime
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=192m; support was removed in 8.0
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 9009
Launching GlassFish on Felix platform
Dec 18, 2018 9:32:43 AM com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner createBundleProvisioner
INFO: Create bundle provisioner class = class com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner.
Dec 18, 2018 9:32:43 AM com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner$DefaultCustomizer getLocations
WARNING: Skipping entry  because it is not an absolute URI.
Dec 18, 2018 9:32:43 AM com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner$DefaultCustomizer getLocations
WARNING: Skipping entry  because it is not an absolute URI.
Registered com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.EmbeddedOSGiGlassFishRuntime@1943da0 in service registry.
Found populator: com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.GFDomainXml
#!## LogManagerService.postConstruct : rootFolder=C:\Program Files\glassfish-4.1\glassfish
#!## LogManagerService.postConstruct : templateDir=C:\Program Files\glassfish-4.1\glassfish\lib\templates
#!## LogManagerService.postConstruct : src=C:\Program Files\glassfish-4.1\glassfish\lib\templates\logging.properties
#!## LogManagerService.postConstruct : dest=C:\Users\nurasahardid\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.0.2\config\GF_4.1\domain1\config\logging.properties
Info:   Running GlassFish Version: GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.1  (build 13)
Info:   Server log file is using Formatter class: com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.ODLLogFormatter
Info:   Realm [admin-realm] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.file.FileRealm] successfully created.
Info:   Realm [file] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.file.FileRealm] successfully created.
Info:   Realm [certificate] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.certificate.CertificateRealm] successfully created.
Info:   Registered org.glassfish.ha.store.adapter.cache.ShoalBackingStoreProxy for persistence-type = replicated in BackingStoreFactoryRegistry
Info:   Authorization Service has successfully initialized.
Info:   Grizzly Framework 2.3.15 started in: 31ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:8080]
Info:   Grizzly Framework 2.3.15 started in: 0ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:8181]
Info:   Grizzly Framework 2.3.15 started in: 0ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:4848]
Info:   Grizzly Framework 2.3.15 started in: 15ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:3700]
Info:   GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.1  (13) startup time : Felix (2,138ms), startup services(1,059ms), total(3,197ms)
Info:   Grizzly Framework 2.3.15 started in: 78ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:7676]
Info:   Registered com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.EmbeddedOSGiGlassFishImpl@6014a9ba as OSGi service registration: org.apache.felix.framework.ServiceRegistrationImpl@107f4980.
Info:   JMXStartupService has started JMXConnector on JMXService URL service:jmx:rmi://10.211.55.3:8686/jndi/rmi://10.211.55.3:8686/jmxrmi
Info:   HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.0.0.Final
Info:   Grizzly Framework 2.3.15 started in: 31ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:8181]
Info:   Grizzly Framework 2.3.15 started in: 0ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:8080]
```

Comment: You need to look at the server log ... like the error message suggests!

Comment: I thought the server log is the one i took the screenshots

Comment: Sorry, but you thought wrong.  Check the GlassFish documentation to find out where the logs files are written, etcetera ...

Comment: *"please help an new to java and netbeans"* - Lesson #1 - find / search / read the documentation!

Comment: @StephenC I have added please i don't know what type of error that is there. could you please take a look.

Comment: You can ignore the warning .... according to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25222861/warning-skipping-entry-because-it-is-not-an-absolute-uri-glassfish-in-netbeans.   For the rest, there don't appear to be any failures.   Are you have configured the server details correctly in your IDE?  Do the timestamps of the log messages correspond with your attempt to deploy?

Comment: One more idea.  If you are trying to use Java 9 or later with Glassfish, that won't work.  Not even Glassfish 5 ... yet.

Comment: @StephenC I couldn't ignore because its not allowed to edit C:\Program Files\glassfish-4.1\glassfish\config/osgi file i have tried changing the core.bundles but still i couldn't save after i edited. My Glassfish server is 4.1